# LIKE is working on BLOB type but = is not working

Tags: java, c, sqlite

I have table with both fields of BLOB data type. I have used sqlite database. I have to insert only binary text into the table.

I have written the program in C. I have inserted successfully.

I have inserted into the table using prepared statement

When I try to find an entry using '=' it is not working. But LIKE gives

`INSERT INTO test1 VALUES('^A~T^F�u�(Z<-~K�~A3���H9�~\�~A[�$D~G%~^|�',"^Q'^K^S^H�~Iq�~Or~N)V��~K�");`

QUERY Statements

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invalid_cert WHERE issuerId='^A~T^F�u�(Z<-~K�~A3���H9�~\�~A[�$D~G%~^|�';`

This statement is giving count as 0

whereas

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invalid_cert WHERE issuerId LIKE '^A~T^F�u�(Z<-~K�~A3���H9�~\�~A[�$D~G%~^|�';`

This statement returns the correct count.

Why is this happening ? 
I have even checked the length of string in table and length of the string which is inserted. Both the lengths are same. I have even checked whether there are any '\n' or '\r' appended to the string. No such string is appended.

Comment: use `strlen` on `^A~T^F�u�(Z<-~K�~A3���H9�~\�~A[�$D~G%~^|�`, and then bind blob to `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invalid_cert WHERE issuerId=?`, this should work. (The insert should also use blob type.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never try to write blobs as strings.
Apart from encoding issues, strings and blobs are not considered equal.

(LIKE works only with strings, so blobs are automatically converted. However, if the blob is not actually a valid UTF-8 string, the conversion can be lossy.)

To use a blob in a query, you can either use parameters:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invalid_cert WHERE issuerId = ?
```

or a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue):

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invalid_cert WHERE issuerId = x'017E5406...'
```

Comment: I tried using prepared statement. It is not working. I will try the other approach.

Comment: The second approach throws `unrecognized token : x'017E5406'`

Comment: Show the complete query. (And you must use the actual value of your blob.)

Comment: The complete quer is `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invalid_cert WHERE issuerId = x'^A~T^F�u�(Z<-~K�~A3���H9�~\�~A[�$D~G%~^|�';` The value is indeed the actual value of blob.

Comment: A blob literal must contain the hex values of the bytes.

Comment: Thanks man :) I did with the help of prepared statements. Thanks a lot :)